# moving(sliding) window average to create base line in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to compute the moving window average with a window size of 20 samples.That window should move throughout the data. Example: For the first 20 samples it will calculate the average and the window moves from 0 to and 20 to 21 and calculate the average from 1 to 21 samples and further it should move on.

I have written a code which 'x' variable is loaded with .dat file and a for loop has been written to calculate mean. The code as follows

```
clear all;
close all;
x= load ('cpp1500.dat');
for i=1:length(x)
    s(i)=sum(x(1:i));
  r(i)=s(i)./i;
end

plot(x,'R')
hold on;
plot(r)
```

Please suggest me a method to calculate the moving window average. 
[Graphs of samples v/s sensor data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5N9k.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's very easy to do.  You would just use the index of your `for` loop to help you compute that for you.  Instead of going from 1 to `i`, you would go from `i` to `i + 19`.  You will need to make sure that your `for` loop doesn't go beyond the bounds of the signal though, so you will need to iterate up to `length(x) - 19`.  You also need to divide your signal by 20 before you go to the next window:

```
clear all;
close all;
x = load ('cpp1500.dat');
for i = 1 : length(x) - 19 % Change
    s(i) = sum(x(i : i + 19)); % Change
    r(i) = s(i) / 20; % Change
end

plot(x,'R');
hold on;
plot(r)
```

---

However, if I can recommend something, don't use a loop here.  Use [`filter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) and specify the right side coefficients as all 1s while the left coefficient is 20.  You also have to be cognizant that there will be a delay because it starts immediately filtering the signal before you have collected 20 samples to get a moving average.  Therefore you will need to remove the first 19 samples from the output after you're done:

```
clear all;
close all;
x = load ('cpp1500.dat');
r = filter(ones(20, 1), 20, x(:));
r = r(20 : end);
plot(x, 'R');
hold on;
plot(r);
```

Note that I have no idea what structure your loaded vector is, so I've ensured that it's a column vector.

Comment: Thank you. The data varies like as graph uploaded in the main question.The mean calculated is taken as a threshold and I want to calculate the transition of the original signal through mean. So, the mean should be calculated without using a filter. As you suggested in the program the mean is calculating till 9980 but the number of samples is  10000. It wants to calculate the mean of all the samples.          I cannot use a filter, as it gives smooth values. I want to have the mean value such that I can compare with the actual data.

Comment: @NagaArjun You will need to remove the last 21 samples at the end of your original signal to do a meaningful comparison. i.e. `xr = x(1:9980);`.  The `filter` syntax already does the mean.  I don't know what it is you want.

Comment: Thank you @rayryeng .I want to calculate the mean of whole samples and   I want to keep that moving mean as a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you seem to have mixed up some of the indexing. To answer the question (this is not the recommended version, for that refer to the version further below)

```
clear all;
close all;
x= load ('cpp1500.dat');
wndSize = 20;
for i=1:length(x) - wndSize
  s(i)=sum(x(i:i + wndSize));
end
r = s ./ wndSize

plot(x,'R')
```

hold on;
plot(r)

Matlab usually punishes looping over arrays with high runtimes. You want to perform a 1d-filtering with a box filter of size 20 where Matlab happens to have efficiently implemented functions. This should do the trick:

```
windowSize = 20; 
b = (1/windowSize)*ones(1,windowSize);
a = 1;

r = filter( b, a, x )
```

Beware that the implementation of filter is slightly different regarding the handling of elements from x that are close than windowSize to the ends of the array. However, it yields a usable sliding average.

See also: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: Be careful with your loop.  This will actually obtain `wndSize + 1` values per sliding window, not `wndSize` as originally desired by the OP.  However, your filter implementation is correct... you will need to remove `windowSize` elements from the output starting at the beginning though.

Answer (score 1):

If you R2016a or later, you can use the [movmean function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) to do this.

```
r = movmean(x, [0 19]);
```

will take a 20-point moving average starting at the current point and using 19 points to the left.  There are other options for the function, depending on how you want to align the window, handle endpoints, tec.